# Solr search result not coming when full keyword is searched

Tags: solr, content-search

I have search results coming based on meta fields Title and Description.
When I search for the partial keyword **"fir"**. results are coming but when I search for the full keyword **"first"** no results are coming.

Below is the code snippet :

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<IndexModel>();
            foreach (var t in searchTerm.Split(' '))
            {
                var searchSplitTerm = t;
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Title.Contains(searchSplitTerm).Boost(20f));
predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.Description.Contains(searchSplitTerm).Boost(10f));
}
```

The description filed contains the below value in Sitecore
lab / first / second.

Comment: did you try PredicateBuilder.False<IndexModel>?

Comment: yes tried but same issue.

Comment: what difference can you see when you see your index query from the search log for both search terms?

Comment: no difference in query just search parameter changes from "fir" to "first"

Comment: same result when you run it in solr dashboard as well?

Comment: from Solr dashboard not able to run contains query.

Comment: Are you using the sitecore_web_index? Has any config been modified? to confirm the value in field is exactly "lab / first / second" with spaces?

Comment: Using  custom index. and value in field is exactly same with spaces.

Comment: You can run contains query in solr dashboard, by going to core then pasting the query from Search.log file. If workng  correctly you should see something like (title_t:(*first*))^20 OR (description_t:(*first*))^10